# Using Scapy to build a Probe Request Request

Tags: python, wireless, scapy

How can I use scapy to send a **IEEE802.11** Probe Request? I have used the following code:

```
srp(Dot11(type=0,subtype=4,addr1 = '00:23:68:a3:28:fc', addr2 = '8c:a9:82:3a:94:5e'), iface = 'wlan0')
```

the addr1 is the dest-AP's Mac address and addr2 is local Mac, but I can't monitor this packet using `wireshark or scapy sniff monitor`, what is wrong?
(When monitoring the packets, I use `airmon-ng start wlan0`  change the mode)

Answer (score 3):

IEEE 802.11 uses CSMA/CA (Carrier Sense Multiple Access with Collision Avoidance) meaning that the card cannot transmit and receive simultaneously.

You need two cards for this to work the way you desire. One specifically in monitor mode to collect the packets, the other is used to transmit your packet.

Check out this video to learn more about Collision Detection/Avoidance. [Youtube Video Explaining CSMA/CD/CA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKkxKG5usaw)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do.  Hope it helps

```
 def sendprobereq_bo_null(target):
  for i in range (1,255):
    radiotap              = RadioTap()
    dot11                 = Dot11(type=0,subtype=0100,addr2=target)
    dot11probereq         = Dot11ProbeReq("00"*i)
    fuzz_frame            = radiotap/dot11/dot11probereq
    hexdump(fuzz_frame)
    sendp(fuzz_frame)
```